# why erases instead of adding in. plist

Tags: ios, plist

I have a code to add data to a plist file object whenever I save my data. they crush of earlier!

I would like them in addition to more! how is this possible?

my code to save my data:

```
// get paths from root direcory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    // set the variables to the values in the text fields
    self.personName = nameEntered.text;
    self.phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
    [phoneNumbers addObject:homePhone.text];
    [phoneNumbers addObject:workPhone.text];
    [phoneNumbers addObject:cellPhone.text];


    // create dictionary with values in UITextFields
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: personName, phoneNumbers, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Phones", nil]];

    NSString *error = nil;
    // create NSData from dictionary
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

    // check is plistData exists
    if(plistData) 
    {
        // write plistData to our Data.plist file
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
        [error release];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the plist file with new data each time. If you want to append then you need to load the existing data from the plist file first, then add your new data to that dictionary, then write out the updated dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents of the plistPath:
    NSMutableData *myData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
And change this:

```
// create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];
```

to:

```
// create NSData from dictionary
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];  
[myData appdendData:plistData];
```

and finally write myData to file.

Hope that helps!